# MEAN stack with Angular cannot "GET"

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I am trying to access MongoDB using the code below from net, but when I am trying to access the URL it says

```
Cannot GET /posts?title=test&link=http://test.com
```

when I am trying to use it like this

```
http://localhost:3000/posts?title=test&link=http://test.com
```

My app.js:

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/news');
require('./models/Posts');
require('./models/Comments');

var routes = require('./routes/index');
var users = require('./routes/users');

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

module.exports = app;
```

and index.js:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();


var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Post = mongoose.model('Post');
var Comment = mongoose.model('Comment');

router.get('/posts', function(req, res, next) {
  Post.find(function(err, posts) {
    if (err) { return next(err); }

    res.json(posts);
  });
});

router.post('/posts', function(req, res, next) {
  var post = new Post(req.body);

  post.save(function(err, post) {
    if (err) { return next(err); }

    res.json(post);
  });
});
```

Posts.js:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var PostSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  title: String,
  link: String,
  upvotes: { type: Number, default: 0 },
  comments: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Comment' }]
});

mongoose.model('Post', PostSchema);
```

Comments.js:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var CommentSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  body: String,
  author: String,
  upvotes: { type: Number, default: 0 },
  post: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Post' }
});

mongoose.model('Comment', CommentSchema);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is not related to mongodb, but you're missing two express-specific points:

1) You need to add `index.js` to you express app, doing something like `app.use('/', require('./routes/index'))`.

2) You need to export the router in `index.js`.